# Using Annotations with Yammer Metrics library

Tags: java, annotations, yammer, codahale-metrics

I am writing a Subclass to the TransportClient of ElasticSearch. (Well that's irrelevant information)

I wanted to calculate the frequency and time statistics across various functions. So I wrote the following Client (Just including some parts to avoid complication)

```
    import com.yammer.metrics.Metrics;
    ...
    public class MikeESClient extends TransportClient
        {
           ...
           private Timer indexTimer, ... ,searchTimer;
           private TimerContext indexTimerContext,..., searchTimerContext;
            //

            //Meters
            private Meter indexMeter,getMeter,updateMeter, deleteMeter, searchMeter;
            //
            private void initial()
                {
                    //intialize the Timers
                    indexTimer= Metrics.newTimer(MikeESClient.class, "index Response", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);.
                .
                .
                .

                    //Timer Initialization Done

                    //Meters
                    indexMeter = Metrics.newMeter(metricName("Index"), "indexing", TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                .
                .
                .

                }
                .
                .
                .
            @Override
            public ActionFuture<IndexResponse> index(IndexRequest request)
                {
                    indexTimerContext = indexTimer.time(); //start timer
                    indexMeter.mark();//meter
                    ActionFuture<IndexResponse>temp=super.index(request);
                    indexTimerContext.stop(); //stop timer
                    return temp;
                }
                .
                .
                .
                similar functions
                .
                .
                .

            @Override
            public void search(SearchRequest request, ActionListener<SearchResponse> listener)
                {
                    searchTimerContext = indexTimer.time(); //start timer
                    searchMeter.mark();//meter
                    super.search(request,listener);
                    searchTimerContext.stop(); //stop timer
                }

        }
```

I have written the similar code of Timer and Meter time and again in the various functions- **index(), get(), update(), delete() & search()** . I came to know that the same thing could be done using Annotations. But unfortunately , I don't know the annotations in java. Well I am curious to know how to use them in java. It would help reduce my code drastically.

I just now simply want to use @Timer, @Meter with default settings. I want to use customised names for the Metrics.